# SWT Java: How to apply transparency to GUI components / controls (e.g button, sashForm, Table etc.)

Tags: java, user-interface, controls, swt, alpha-transparency

I would like to apply the same effect as shell.setAlpha(240), however was browsing the internet for couple of hours and still didn't found the solution.

Reason: I decided to improve visual appearance for application. I applied abstract image to shell background and it is only visible around of controls, which is not visually perfect.

Therefore, I want to apply light transparency to certain controls such as tables, so it will become nicer.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to set the transparency to inherit background from Composite. Use `Composite.setBackgroundMode()` to set `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE`. Here is a [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet237.java) that can help